# Parse HTML by DIV ID

Tags: html, powershell, parsing

I am trying to parse the actual value from the webpage, however, I am only able to pull the source code instead of the value.

HTML code:

```html
<div id="UpdateString">As of 9/10 /20178:46:24 AM, We are currently UP with 2210 servers. Next update in 5 Minutes.</div>
```

PowerShell code:

```bsh
$URI = "http://example.com"
$HTML = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI
($HTML.ParsedHtml.GetElementsByTagName('div') |
    Where { $_.id -eq 'UpdateString' }).InnerText
```

I am trying to extract the value "2210".

Comment: Your HTML doesn't match the Powershell code. The `div`'s `id` in HTML is `UpdateString` but you're looking for an `id` containing `currently` in Powershell.

Comment: I have tried both...it doesn't output anything

Comment: I would suggest try seeing what powershell reads `$HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('div') | Where{ $_.id -ne ""} | ft`as  and see what the id row is displaying... that will give you what goes in your where statement.

Comment: `(...).InnerText -replace '.*with (\d+) servers.*', '$1'`?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I tried that I don't get any result.

Comment: What do you get without the replacement operation?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers it returns nothing.

Comment: You *did* replace the ellipsis with the rest of the statement from your question, didn't you? Did you try with `IHTMLDocument3_GetElementsByTagName()`?